# match fields in logstash with "$"

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to match specific fields if they contain the symbol "$"

Data Sample :

```
"SubjectUserName": "HOSTNAME$"
```

logstash Config:

```
if [SubjectUserName] =~ [A-Z]+\$ {
#do stuff
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What is the actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from your example: `if [SubjectUserName] =~ [A-Z]+\$ {`.

It actually means: Check whether somewhere in `SubjectUserName` occurs:

- `[A-Z]+` - a non-empty sequence of letters,
- `\$` - and then a dollar char.

Both before and after this match there can occur any other text.

So if you want **only** to check for presence of a dollar char, somewhere
in the mentioned field, the regex should probably be:

```
if [SubjectUserName] =~ \$ {
```

Comment: thanks it's work, I just add `if [SubjectUserName] =~ /\$/ {`